# Web Analytics on Intranet

Tags: intranet

There are some great web analytics tools in the internet (ClickTale, CrazyEgg, etc.).  However, they only work if the site has access to the internet.  I have an intranet site on a corporate network that can't access the internet and I'd like to run similar analytics (heatmaps, clicks, etc).  Are there any self-host options?  Preferably free.

thanks

Comment: We use Angelfish Software for tracking our Intranet sites.  Self hosted.

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) -- open source, PHP/MySQL tool offering information and UI similar to Google Analytics.

They have a [live demo](http://piwik.org/demo/index.php?module=CoreHome&action=index&idSite=1&period=day&date=yesterday#module=Dashboard&action=embeddedIndex&idSite=1&period=day&date=yesterday) as well.

Comment: that's a good start.  however, I need it to show clicks on a page (e.g. heatmaps or page stats).  it doesn't seem like Piwik does this...

Comment: ah, true. No heatmaps

Answer (score 1):

[Clickheat](http://www.labsmedia.com/clickheat/index.html) for heatmaps.

Comment: Simple Mouse Tracking http://smt.speedzinemedia.com/smt/